# UpdateNonDefaults is not working with ServiceStack for Boolean Value

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack ORMLite with Sql Server. Now in my Servicestack , POCO class i have a `boolean` field which is represented by `bit not null` in Sql Server . Now i want this boolean value to be updated lets say from true to false and vice-versa.But this is not happening , apart from that boolean column all other columns are getting updated correctly.I am using following line to perform update operation..

```
db.UpdateNonDefaults(ChangeBool, p => p.id== request.StudentId);
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use **NonDefaults** API to do this since **false** is the default value for a boolean and `UpdateNonDefaults()` only updates **non default** values.

You can instead use UpdateOnly and specify that you want to update the bool column, e.g:

```
db.UpdateOnly(new ChangeBool { Bool = false }, 
    onlyFields: x => x.Bool, 
    where: x => x.Id == request.StudentId);
```

Comment: I small Doubt , How to add more than one field in `onlyFields: x => x.Bool,` as i need to update one more column in the table. From the Object of `new ChangeBool` its not happening ..

Comment: @Lara you can use `onlyFields: new { x.Bool, x.Foo }`